# Block or single line elements

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to display 3 elements in a single line when space available for all the 3 and if not, display each of them in a single separate row?

So if i can show 3 inline ok, but I'd like to avoid 2 elements in a row and the last in the next row.
The requisite is to preferably NOT use media query.

Comment: Do you know width of elements?

Comment: You need a script or a media query to solve that...and I recommend media query :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with Javascript or jQuery as below. It gets the width of each element. If the sum of these is more than the width of the wrapper element, it converts the elements from `display: inline-block` to `display: block`, thereby making them 100% wide:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var L1 = $(".x1").width();
  var L2 = $(".x2").width();
  var L3 = $(".x3").width();
  var sum = L1 + L2 + L3;
  var availableSpace = $(".wrapper").innerWidth();
  if (availableSpace < sum) {
    $(".x").css('display', 'block');
  };
})
```

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
}

.x {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
<div class="x x1">11111111111 11111111111111 11111111111111</div><div class="x x2">2222222222222 2222222222222 222222222222</div><div class="x x3">333333333333 333333333333333333</div>
</div>
```

Make the snippet fullscreen to see the effect. Instead of the `.wrapper` DIV you could also just use `body` in the jQuery function, if you don't have a parent element around those three elements.

Comment: OP has not added javascript or jquery tag. I think he is looking for css only solution that too without media queries.

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj which is not possible, why I provided this solution. Apart from that, he only worte "no media queries", but not "no javascript"